# XSLT creating new tags from the value in other tags

Tags: xml, xslt, tags

Please can someone help a newbie who is really struggling.
I am new to XSL and I just cannot work this out.
I can get it close, but cannot get the `<Material_Data>`, `<Material>` and 
`<Comp_Class>` tags sorted.  Below is the source document:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Variable_Attributes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\ZZ\Test Var Attribs.xsd">
    <Material>1</Material>
    <Comp_Class>Aerosol - Aluminium</Comp_Class>
    <Material_Data>
        <Field_Name>ZMDM_Diameter</Field_Name>
        <Field_Value>45</Field_Value>
        <Field_Name>ZMDM_Height</Field_Name>
        <Field_Value>60</Field_Value>
        <Field_Name>ZMDM_Supplier</Field_Name>
        <Field_Value>Tony</Field_Value>
        <Field_Name>ZMDM_Brimful</Field_Name>
        <Field_Value>78</Field_Value>
        <Field_Name>ZMDM_Size</Field_Name>
        <Field_Value>440</Field_Value>
    </Material_Data>
    <Material>2</Material>
    <Comp_Class>Aerosol Valves</Comp_Class>
    <Material_Data>
        <Field_Name>ZMDM_UoM</Field_Name>
        <Field_Value>EA</Field_Value>
        <Field_Name>ZMDM_Free_Text</Field_Name>
        <Field_Value>Test Aerosol</Field_Value>
        <Field_Name>ZMDM_Size</Field_Name>
        <Field_Value>18</Field_Value>
    </Material_Data>
</Variable_Attributes>
```

what I need to get to is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Material_Data>
    <Material>1</Material>
    <Comp_Class>Aerosol - Aluminium</Comp_Class>
    <ZMDM_Diameter>45</ZMDM_Diameter>
    <ZMDM_Height>60</ZMDM_Height>
    <ZMDM_Supplier>Tony</ZMDM_Supplier>
    <ZMDM_Brimful>78</ZMDM_Brimful>
    <ZMDM_Size>440</ZMDM_Size>
    <ZMDM_UoM>EA</ZMDM_UoM>
</Material_Data>
<Material_Data>
    <Material>2</Material>
    <Comp_Class>Aerosol Valves</Comp_Class>
    <ZMDM_Free_Text>Test Aerosol</ZMDM_Free_Text>
    <ZMDM_Size>18</ZMDM_Size>
</Material_Data>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Steve

Below is what I have tried so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Material_Data>
            <xsl:for-each select="/Variable_Attributes/Material_Data/Field_Name">
                <xsl:variable name="val" select="current()"/>
                <xsl:variable name="val2" select="current()/following-sibling::*[1]"/>
                <xsl:element name="{$val}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$val2"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Material_Data>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You expected output document is malformed. You can only have one root element. Please update your question to have a valid expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an `xsl:for-each`, trying using a template based approach.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Variable_Attributes">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Material_Data|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Material_Data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::Material[1]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::Comp_Class[1]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Field_Name"/>
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Field_Name">
        <xsl:element name="{.}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Field_Value[1]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Field_Value">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<Variable_Attributes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\ZZ\Test Var Attribs.xsd">
   <Material_Data>
      <Material>1</Material>
      <Comp_Class>Aerosol - Aluminium</Comp_Class>
      <ZMDM_Diameter>45</ZMDM_Diameter>
      <ZMDM_Height>60</ZMDM_Height>
      <ZMDM_Supplier>Tony</ZMDM_Supplier>
      <ZMDM_Brimful>78</ZMDM_Brimful>
      <ZMDM_Size>440</ZMDM_Size>
   </Material_Data>
   <Material_Data>
      <Material>2</Material>
      <Comp_Class>Aerosol Valves</Comp_Class>
      <ZMDM_UoM>EA</ZMDM_UoM>
      <ZMDM_Free_Text>Test Aerosol</ZMDM_Free_Text>
      <ZMDM_Size>18</ZMDM_Size>
   </Material_Data>
</Variable_Attributes>
```

Comment: DevNull.  I just can't thank you enough.  I am so grateful.  
Thanks God for you and stackoverflow.

Comment: What DevNull didn't do was to point out where you went wrong. It's quite possible to solve the problem using a pull-style stylesheet with for-each; but you need one for-each "loop" for each level in the output hierarchy, and one of your levels was missing.

Comment: @MichaelKay - Yes, thank you for the comment. I missed the most important part of the answer!